# spark - join one to many relationship dataframes

Tags: apache-spark

Lets take the following toy problem, I've got the following case classes:

```
case class Order(id: String, name: String, status: String)
case class TruncatedOrder(id: String)
case class Org(name: String, ord: Seq[TruncatedOrder])
```

I've now got the following defined variables

```
val ordersDF = Seq(Order("or1", "stuff", "shipped"), Order("or2", "thigns", "delivered") , Order("or3", "thingamabobs", "never received"), Order("or4", "???", "what?")).toDS()
val orgsDF = Seq(Org("tupper", Seq(TruncatedOrder("or1"), TruncatedOrder("or2"), TruncatedOrder("or3"))), Org("ware", Seq(TruncatedOrder("or3"), TruncatedOrder("or4")))).toDS()
```

What I would like is to have for example a datapoint that looks as follows
`Ord("tupper", Array(Joined("or1", "stuff", "shipped"), Joined("or2", "things", "delivered"), ...)`

Im wondering how to format my `join` statements and filter statements.

Comment: Did you try saving the `DF` as `temp table` and write the query? Once you are comfortable with that, you can convert the same using DataFrame API.

Comment: @Shankar I hadn't thought about that, how do you see that temp table being used?

Comment: you can store the df to temple  `ordersdf.registerTempTable("orders")`, then using `sqlContext.sql("write sql query with join and where condition")`

Comment: You can look into this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to get the data into the format that I wanted. This answer is inspired a lot by the answers provided by @ulrich and @Mariusz.

```
val ud = udf((col: String, name: String, status: String) => { Seq(col, name, status)})

orgsDF
  .select($"name".as("ordName"),explode($"ord.id"))
  .join(ordersDF, $"col" === $"id").drop($"id")
  .select($"ordName", ud($"col", $"name", $"status"))
  .groupBy($"ordName")
  .agg(collect_set($"order"))
  .show()

    +-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |ordName|orders                                                                                                                    |
    +-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |ware   |[WrappedArray(or4, ???, what?), WrappedArray(or3, thingamabobs, never received)]                                          |
    |tupper |[WrappedArray(or1, stuff, shipped), WrappedArray(or2, thigns, delivered), WrappedArray(or3, thingamabobs, never received)]|
    +-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
spark.conf.set("HiveSupport.enabled", true)

orgsDF.select('name,explode('ord))
      .map {case row: Row =>(row(0).toString,row(1).toString.filterNot("[]()".contains(_))) }.toDF("name",("ord"))
      .join(ordersDF.select('id,'status,'name.as("name2") ),'ord === 'id).drop("id")
      .select('name,concat('ord, lit(","),'Status, lit(","),'name2 ).as("info"))
      .groupBy('name) 
      .agg(collect_set('info))
      .show()
```

Which returns

```
+------+--------------------+
|  name|   collect_set(info)|
+------+--------------------+
|  ware|[[or3,never recei...|
|tupper|[[or1,shipped,stu...|
+------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One to many is easy tu write if you follow these steps:

1. Use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) to flatten `orgsDF`
2. Perform standard inner join
3. Use [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) to aggregate by `tuppler`-thing

Comment: Both collections are nearly 1tb in size, Im not so sure how `collect` anything would even be possible.

Comment: `collect_list` is an aggreation function and - in opposite to `collect()` terminal operation - does not send any results to the driver. Try it out!